# Show that there is a point with a minimum norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

This is the question I have to prove, can anyone help me with that?

$\mathbb E$ $\subset$ $\mathbb R^n$ is compact set and  $\vec 0$ $\notin$ $\mathbb E$.

Show that there exist $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb E$ with minimum norm That is
,such that for each $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb E$,

**Existing that : $\lVert x\rVert$ $\le $ $\lVert y\rVert$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=\inf \{\|y\|: y \in \mathbb E\}$. Then there exist a sequence $(y_n)$ in $\mathbb E$ such that $\|y_n\|\to r$. There is  subsequence $(y_{n_k})$ which converges to some point $x$. Can you show that $x \in \mathbb E$ and  $\|x\|=r$?

Comment: Can you help me to show that $\|x\|=r$?

Comment: @AmitBenDavid the norm is a continuous function.